# How long of a game is Evoland?

Tags: evoland

So, I'm considering buying [Evoland](http://store.steampowered.com/app/233470?l=english), and I want to know about how much content is in it? Is it a 40 hour game? A shorter 2 hour game? What can I expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it took around 3 hours straight with some exploring to find hidden stars and Double Twin cards. I've completed it to 90.4%.

So depending on your play style and how fast you get the pattern in the game and with taking the time to find all hidden stuffs to get 100% completion... maybe 4 hours.

BTW, most of players report that it's hard to get to 100%, must of them only got 99.1%

Answer (score 5):

According to reports and a developer comment on the Steam discussion group, it is about 3-6h of game time. Your personal experience may vary, depending on your play style.

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/233470/discussions/0/828935361135637671/)